# Subquery with GROUP_CONCAT & CONCAT returns STILL more than 1 row, Error 1242

Tags: sql, mariadb, subquery, group-concat

I get the this error:

> "Error 1242 more than 1 row"

even I allready use group_concat ..

here is my query which gives me the error

```
SELECT 
`coms_participant_exam_event`.`coms_exam_event_id` AS PEE_ID,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT((SELECT CONCAT(`bpmspace_coms_v1`.`state`.`name`," (",`coms_participant_exam_event`.`state_id`,") ",  count(`coms_participant_exam_event`.`state_id`))  
FROM `coms_participant_exam_event`
JOIN `bpmspace_coms_v1`.`state` ON
    (
            `bpmspace_coms_v1`.`state`.`state_id` =
            `bpmspace_coms_v1`.`coms_participant_exam_event`.`state_id`
    )
where `coms_exam_event_id` = `coms_participant_exam_event`.`coms_exam_event_id`
group by `bpmspace_coms_v1`.`coms_participant_exam_event`.`state_id`) , ','))
FROM `coms_participant_exam_event`
group by `coms_participant_exam_event`.`coms_exam_event_id`
```

when I "hardcode" the `coms_exam_event_id` with an id the only has 1 row as result it is working - no  clue why the GROUP_CONCAT is not enough

```
SELECT 
`coms_participant_exam_event`.`coms_exam_event_id` AS PEE_ID,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT((SELECT CONCAT(`bpmspace_coms_v1`.`state`.`name`," (",`coms_participant_exam_event`.`state_id`,") ",  count(`coms_participant_exam_event`.`state_id`))  
FROM `coms_participant_exam_event`
JOIN `bpmspace_coms_v1`.`state` ON
    (
            `bpmspace_coms_v1`.`state`.`state_id` =
            `bpmspace_coms_v1`.`coms_participant_exam_event`.`state_id`
    )
where `coms_exam_event_id` = 877523
group by `bpmspace_coms_v1`.`coms_participant_exam_event`.`state_id`),','))
FROM `coms_participant_exam_event`
group by `coms_participant_exam_event`.`coms_exam_event_id`
```

Thanks for your help
rob

Answer (score 0):

Looks like count is not allowed in group_concat.
I created an HELP VIEW with the "select concat ... count ... part" and then did the group_concat from the view ...